# how do you select all tables and all field in mysql?

Tags: php, mysqli

My database have four tables i.e physics, chemistry, biology and maths respectively.   Every table has the same column names like studentName, registrationNumber, mark.
My question is when I search with registrationNumber I want to get every fields of mark in every table.  How can I query such a way?  Please explain it with simple example.  Thanks in advance (this example is only for the problem presenting purpose only)

Comment: can you show your database structure?

Comment: You should re-organise your table structure to have only one table for all courses and a table with all students. These you can link together with another table and that way you can easily manage and search for information. And it makes it very easy to add courses...

Comment: why this question got an upvote, is beyond me.

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO! Please read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) post for how to ask better questions, which will help people give you better answers. In particular, add the code of what you've already tried.

Comment: @Fred-ii- It's amazing how many questions start with an upvote within seconds...

Comment: @jeroen Amazing usually baffles me.

Comment: and now, answers are starting to roll in like oranges.

Comment: *"respected sir,"* - don't leave the ladies out of this ;-)

Answer (score 1):

I agree with @NareshKumar that normalization is one option.  But if you must use your current schema you could do a `UNION` query:

```
SELECT studentName, registrationNumber, mark, 'physics' AS class
FROM physics
WHERE registrationNumber = N
UNION ALL
SELECT studentName, registrationNumber, mark, 'chemistry' AS class
FROM chemistry
WHERE registrationNumber = N
SELECT studentName, registrationNumber, mark, 'biology' AS class
FROM biology
WHERE registrationNumber = N
SELECT studentName, registrationNumber, mark, 'maths' AS class
FROM maths
WHERE registrationNumber = N
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems we've had the same idea with `@Tim Biegeleisen` and he did it better, so I will just redirect you to [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37189574/5854688).

Comment: You should add a computed column for each query which would identify from which class table each record comes.

Answer (score 0):

You should use normalization to store the marks in single table instead of making different table for each subject    [Normalization](http://www.w3schools.in/dbms/database-normalization/)